# How do I delete all Terminal mail?

Tags: terminal, email, unix

I set up a cronjob a long time ago that now doesn't exist. Whenever I open up Terminal, it now says "You have mail". I have something like 100 messages that all say the same thing. How do I mass delete all of the messages?

Comment: I wasn't even aware an MTA was built into OS X. Though now that I think about it, frankly I'm not surprised.

Comment: @JasonSalaz I forgot to ask you, what's an MTA?

Comment: Mail Transfer Agent. When in doubt, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_Transfer_Agent). I know of, at least, MTAs, MSAs, MDAs, and MUAs.

Answer (score 330, accepted):

Launch the UNIX `mail` utility by running the following at the command prompt (in e.g. Terminal.app):

```
$ mail
```

You'll see a list of all your messages. From the mail prompt, do

```
? delete *
? q
```

And that should be it. Make sure to enter `q` after the `delete *` command. This will save the changes to disk.

Comment: At first I didn't know what mail app mean. To anyone who is having same trouble, "It is a command". Just go type it in terminal and you will get an interactive app running there. +1 Thank you

Comment: You can use ``del 1`` where 1 is the message number too in case you need to keep some email for debugging purposes.

Comment: kept following other answers but used `exit` to quit and would not work. Thanks for mentioning the `q` option.

Comment: Anyone else visit this answer monthly?

Comment: `d *` also works

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works on my macOS 13.4

Answer (score 18):

You may also go the direct route and just run `: > /var/mail/$USER` to empty the mail file.

PS: Deleting the mail file requires sudo, just setting it to empty is enough.

Answer (score 5):

I want to reinforce clearly one point how command **[delete *],[q]** really helped me out in this case.

I set a cron job to run like every day in 2018 (if I recall correctly) and forgot about it.

Now I realized to check and I discovered 3000 messages in my mailbox! Note to others that a quick edit can pile up reports rapidly.

Answer (score 4):

I know this post is old, but I want to contribute with an answer.

to delete your mail messages do the following:

```
sudo rm /var/mail/[user]
```

And in order to the question, I suggest you do the following to each crontab you do not want to send an email notification (this way your mail will not have mails)

```
* * * * * /path/to/script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

or

```
* * * * * command > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Notice that you should probably not drop `stderr` (FD 2). You usually want to be notified about errors so this is something which should be accessible.